# Are there some tricks to decide whether a space is path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

An exercise in Munkres' Topology asks us to decide whether a given space, such as product space and the closure of a path-connected subset of a space $X$, is path-connected.

I'd like to know if there are some  tricks to decide whether a space is path-connected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Most obvious: given two arbitrary points, try to construct a path.  This should work for the product problem (hint: if the factors are path connected, then this provides you with some paths to work with...)
- Look for counterexamples.  The topologist's sine curve and its variants are the most commonly encountered counterexamples to path connectedness.  This should help you disprove the closure problem (consider the set $\{(t, \sin(1/t)): 0 < t < 1\}$).
- Useful theorem: if a space is connected and locally path connected, then it is path connected.  This is useful for open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Digesting the proof of this theorem will also provide some helpful insight into working with path connectedness.